# html button muliple line align

Tags: html, css, button, vertical-alignment

I need some help with the following button alignment issue within html and css.

The following [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HeavenlyHost/3g1he0ao/) shows the problem

```
<div>
  <button style="height:100px">
    <div style="display:table">
      <div style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle">
        bob
        <p>
          bill
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </button>
  <button style="height:100px">
    <div style="display:table">
      <div style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle">
        bob
      </div>
    </div>
  </button>
</div>
```

How do I get the buttons vertically aligned with their contents in the middle of themselves ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need this:

```css
button{
  height:100px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.outer{
  display:table;
}

.inner{
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
.inner p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button>
    <div class="outer">
      <div class="inner">
      bob
      <p>
        bill
      </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </button>
  <button>
    <div class="outer">
      <div class="inner">
        bob
      </div>
    </div>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't ask the OP to check your answer it's considered rude.

Comment: ta very much vertical align top on the button resolved my issue

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is invalid.

`button` elements cannot contain divs.

```css
button {
  height: 100px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button>
    <span>bob</br>
   bill</span>
  </button>
  <button>
    <span>bob</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. **CSS Flex-box**

```css
.add_class{
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}
button{
  height:100px;
  margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="add_class">
  <button>
    <div class="outer">
      <div class="inner">
      bob
      <p>
        bill
      </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </button>
  <button>
    <div class="outer">
      <div class="inner">
        bob
      </div>
    </div>
  </button>
</div>
```